# how to maximise window size in htmlunit driver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit-driver

I am running selenium test using HtmlUnitDriver but at some point test keep failing. Is there any way we can maximize the window size in HtmlUnitDriver?

Comment: At what point does it fail?

Answer (score 0):

To maximize the window just use [HtmlUnitWindow](https://www.selenium.dev/htmlunit-driver/org/openqa/selenium/htmlunit/HtmlUnitDriver.HtmlUnitWindow.html) `maximize()`

```
HtmlUnitDriver htmlDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
htmlDriver.HtmlUnitWindow().maximize()
```